# Issue with GIF Content Rendering in Comments via the Instagram API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Using API Graph Instagram getting comments on Media https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/media_id/comments.
Currently, the API functions correctly in fetching comments, however, I am facing a significant challenge: GIF content within these comments is not rendering correctly.
My objective is to ensure that GIF content within comments can be retrieved correctly.
Does someone have already faced on the same situation, do you have any idea how to get gif content  ?
Thank you so much

Comment: Are they "not rendering correctly" (and if so, what would that actually _mean_?), or do you not get them returned in the response, anywhere, at all? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-comment#fields lists no extra "attachments" fields or similar, so I would guess if anything, you'd only find them as part of the `text`.

Comment: Hello, the item "text" is missing, I mean not rendering in the response of the API,
with fields=attachments I get as response  "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (attachments) on node type (ShadowIGComment)" , so I guess this field does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, a customer complain they don't get any text/media.
I've reviewed and find that the comments that were missing were comments replied with gifs.
The api does not return any text/attachments, (for these comments docs do not include the attachments field).

sorry you are facing this issue too, I'm also looking for a way to overcome this.

here's a link to a bug report
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1017438549660525/

which sadly we can no longer reopen, and with bugs on api no longer being able to create FB bug reports, the forums do not offer much help
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/927161448366658/